# ¿Cómo debo etiquetar las preguntas SQL?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Cuando se hace una pregunta pidiendo ayuda para armar una consulta SQL, ¿cual es la forma adecuada de ponerle o editar las etiquetas a la pregunta?

Hago la pregunta porque me doy cuenta que no todos estamos concordando totalmente, y quisiera que se haga de una forma más uniforme.

Más específicamente, he notado casos donde la etiqueta [`sql`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) se está removiendo de la pregunta a favor de solo dejar la etiqueta que especifica la base de datos que usa OP.

Aunque voy a publicar mi recomendación personal en una respuesta, mi deseo es simplemente que se llegue a un consenso, aunque no concuerde con mi preferencia personal.

Answer (score 3):

La forma como yo lo he hecho siempre es que la pregunta incluya por lo menos 2 etiquetas (tal vez 3):

- la etiqueta mas general [`sql`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)
- la etiqueta específica a la base de datos que se usa. Ejemplo: [`sql-server`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info)
- Opcionalmente (y adicionalmente), si es relevante, la etiqueta para la versión específica a la base de datos que se está usando. Ejemplo: [`sql-server-2008-r2`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server-2008-r2/info). Esto es particularmente útil cuando el que pregunta está usando una versión anterior a la corriente.
- Se pueden agregar otras etiquetas que sean relevantes, pero siempre se intentaría incluir las anteriores en prioridad.

Esta es la forma usual de hacerlo en la versión inglesa del sitio. Tiene las ventajas siguientes:

- El que siempre se incluya la etiqueta [`sql`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) permite que alguien que solo sigue esa etiqueta pueda encontrar todas las preguntas relacionadas a armar consultas SQL, sin importar la base de datos.
- El que siempre se incluya la etiqueta [`sql`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) permite que el código SQL siempre quede bonito (syntax highlighting) sin importar cuales otras etiquetas están incluídas.
- Pero a la vez, el que se incluya la etiqueta  para la base de datos permite que los que contesten usen un sabor del lenguaje SQL que funcione correctamente en esa base de datos.
- Y aunque no es tan esencial como las etiquetas anteriores, el que se incluya adicionalmente la etiqueta con la versión específica evita que se den respuestas que solo funcionan con versiones mas nuevas de la base de datos, y no con la que usa OP. Por ejemplo, si la pregunta incluye la etiqueta [`sql-server-2008-r2`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server-2008-r2/info), dependiendo del tipo de consulta que se necesita, esa información puede sumamente útil para determinar la mejor forma de escribir la consulta.

Que yo sepa, siempre se ha considerado buena práctica de incluir etiquetas un poco mas generales, como es la etiqueta [`sql`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) (para mayor visibilidad), junto con etiquetas más específicas, como las etiquetas de bases de datos específicos y/o con versiones específicas (para limitar las respuestas aceptables).

Aunque no es 100% idéntico, la idea sigue el principio encontrado en la pregunta meta siguiente: [Should I not use the generic tag if my solution is limited to a specific version?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version).

Traduciendo parte de la pregunta:

> ¿Debería evitar usar la etiqueta más genérica si mi proyecto está limitado a una versión específica?
>
> Otra vez tuve una pregunta donde la etiqueta más genérica fue removida. La descripción para la edición fue: "Eliminando etiquetas redundantes". Esto hizo que me preguntara: ¿hize mal en incluir tanto la etiqueta más específica y la más general?
>
> Sé que incluir la etiqueta mas específica fue lo correcto. Pero cuando hago eso, ¿debería evitar incluir la etiqueta mas general también? Entiendo que pueda ser redundante, pero a la vez, el que solo incluya la etiqueta de la versión específica limita bastante la cantidad de personas que vean mi pregunta, y puede que la solución no sea exclusiva a mi versión específica.

Traduciendo una parte de la respuesta aceptada:

> Haces bien en seguir incluyendo la etiqueta más genérica. La etiqueta más general sirve para atraer a los expertos, mientras que la etiqueta más específica comunica que el problema se limita a una versión específica.

Comment: Sobre las etiquetas: `SQL` es si tienes problemas particulares con el lenguaje estructurado de consultas. Hay mucha gente que confunde SQL con SQL Server, por ello a veces conviene colocar solo la etiqueta principal. Ahora, sobre la etiqueta particular de la versión de SQL Server, solo aplica si tu problema es específico para esa versión, de lo contrario se asume que es un problema general para ese motor de bd.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con etiquetar con ambas (o con las 3), y es como vengo etiquetando en cada edición. Creo que el paraguas de [tag:SQL] es la mejor forma de seguir y buscar publicaciones. Adicionalmente, creo que deberíamos mejorar la descripción de las etiquetas para que quede aún más claro.

Comment: @Luiggi siendo tu opinión radicalmente diferente a esta respuesta, creo que convendría publicar como respuesta y permitir que la comunidad vote.

Comment: Hola @Luiggi. Gracias por comentar. Lo que mencionas, ¿es una norma establecida en SOes de la cual no estoy al tanto, o es tu opinión? Pregunto, porque aunque entiendo tu lógica, es muy diferente de la forma como se acostumbra hacer en SOen. Y aunque entiendo que este sitio no necesita copiar todas las normas de la versión en inglés, creo que es razonable asumir las mismas normas hasta que la comunidad decida diferentemente. Estoy de acuerdo con Mariano que una respuesta exponiendo el punto de vista alternativo al mío se apreciaría.

Comment: Es norma de SOen y la verdad así se está aplicando en las versiones de tecnologías/frameworks como python vs python 3. Usar una regla distinta en el caso de motores de bases de datos relacionales, no me psrece apropiado.

Comment: @Luiggi: Eso son noticias para mi. ¿Tienes alguna referencia al respecto? Porque, si hay una etiqueta en la que he participado extensamente en SOen, es la de SQL. Y la forma como lo describo en mi respuesta arriba es la forma como siempre lo he visto en SOen y es la que he encontrado sumamente práctico para poder encontrar las preguntas SQL, pero a la vez tener toda la información pertinente necesaria para poder dar respuestas acertadas.

Comment: Respuestas, pero aquí hablamos de etiquetas

Comment: Ahorita no estoy en un equipo. Cuando lo esté (posiblemene mañana) buscaré las pruebas de lo que comento.

Comment: @Luiggi: Ok, se agradece ;)

Comment: Amplío sobre mi visión: [python] vs. [python3] es la forma en que los expertos lo llaman. Pero [sql] es la forma de especificar una pregunta sobre el lenguaje de consultas, en la cual es necesario especificar el DBMS para poder responder. Esto las diferencia, por ejemplo, de preguntas acerca una configuración específica de [sql-server] (sin [sql]). También la diferencia de preguntas cómo implementar algo de una base de datos en un lenguaje de programación específico, por ejemplo [php][mysql].

Comment: @Luiggi Si vas a publicar una respuesta (realmente no hay apuro, ya es feriado puente, por lo menos acá) no entiendo, según tu visión, en qué caso se usaría la etiqueta [sql] y te pido que lo aclares (teniendo en cuenta que una pregunta de [sql] (el lenguaje de consultas) no se puede responder sin especificar el motor).

Comment: De http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info "*Esta etiqueta debería usarse para preguntas generales del lenguaje de programación SQL, además de las etiquetas de los productos específicos* (...) *SQL es el paraguas bajo el cual estos productos existen*" ... Y luego pone como una excepción habitual "*Es muy común que las preguntas con [mysql] omitan esta etiqueta*" (habitual, pero no obligatorio)... Lo cual es cierto, [mysql] puede entenderse por separado, pero no es lo mismo para [sql-server].

Comment: ¿Se consensuó este uso?

Comment: @fedorqui: Dado que no hubo suficiente participación en este hilo, diría que no llegamos a un consenso del todo.

Comment: Gracias @sstan por la información. Relancémoslo algún día, a ver si se puede acordar algo.